# Is possible to integrate Bootstrap in App Maker?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-app-maker

I want to integrate Bootstrap in an App Maker application. I have seen that there is an option to add external resources in the App Settings where we can add resources via cdn.

[image]

As you can see I have tried to add Bootstrap but it's not working... 
I have created an html panel where I want to put the bootstrap style.

[image]

[image]

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work without any problem so far on my testing. What you are required to do is to `allowUnsafeHtml` on the HTML widget.

[image]

The bootstrapped button will show only after you preview the app:

[image]